# Transactional not able to resolve transaction boundaries - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions, transactional

I am trying to do a simple saveOrUpdate operation using a Transaction Manager in Hibernate but, the context is not flushed to the DB tables. I suspect, the Transaction Manager is not able to resolve the end of the transaction and hence, doesn't flush the changes.

The changes are reflected in the DB Table if a session.flush() is done explicitly. I am using the Default flush mode, which is AUTO.

There are a couple of other questions on SO that talk about the same, but none of them have helped in my case.

```
@Transactional(transactionManager="txManager", readOnly=false)
    public Integer setNamesTable(Names names) {
    session = getSession();
    Integer id = null;
    if (session != null) {
        try {
            id = (Integer) session.save(names);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } 
        LOGGER.info("Exiting setNmlAggrTcaPhn");
        }
    return id;
}
```

Have Autowired SessionFactory as below,

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("hibernateTestAnnotatedSessionFactory")
SessionFactory sfc;

private synchronized Session getSession() {
    try {
            session = sf.getCurrentSession();
            if (session != null) {
            return session;
            } else {
            session = sf.openSession();
            }
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            session = sf.openSession();
        }
    return session;
    }
```

Comment: You're creating a new ApplicationContext in your getSession() method - how is your application starting up? Using Spring? Why aren't they in the same application context?

Comment: That is pretty surely, because you create the `ApplicationContext` each time you need a session. A transaction should only happen after the `SessionFactory` has already been created

Comment: Since this is a local project, triggered as a java application in Eclipse, I need to load the Spring.xml every time and get the Session Factory object.

Comment: Then you need to @Autowire your SessionFactory in the class above and your test class should create the application context then lookup and call your transactional method... Check out the spring-test classes/annotations

Comment: I tried Autowiring SessionFactory, but no luck !!

Comment: Have edited my question to Autowire Session Factory.

Comment: your getSession() method looks a bit complicated, is getCurrentSession() returning null? If you're creating a session using openSession then Spring transactions won't work, you need to use getCurrentSession(). Also, why is the catch also opening a session?

Comment: Yes, my getCurrentSession() returns null. Hence, I must do an openSession() to get a session object.

Comment: The Spring managed transaction won't work with openSession, you have to get the currentSession opened by Spring. If it's returning null that means you haven't started your Spring applicationContext, can you show the code that does that?